# mplayer video screen is disappearing

Tags: 12.04, mplayer

When I am trying to open any video file [ `.mp4`, `.mkv`, `.flv` so far ] with `mplayer` from right click context menu on Nautilus, the following things are happening:

- audio is playing but video playing screen is just disappearing.
- the control box is still there and able to pause, stop etc from it.
- sometimes after pausing/stopping the file, video screen is appearing and `mplayer` is freezing. To stop it I had to kill it.

If I run those same videos with `mplayer` from a `terminal` everything is fine without any issue. Only the control box is not there (I think this is default, I don't have an issue with it).